# Can it be possible to use trigger in java controller spring

Tags: spring-mvc, triggers

Is there a way to run AFTER EACH ROW trigger in java (spring 2.5 controller). I am using sql developer. I want trigger in java code controller.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: You need to explain your requirement in more detail and possibly with some code.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I have a table called Sinirlama. When I insert record in this table, the trigger AFTER EACH ROW run and this trigger insert record into the SinirlamaLog table. This works well in sql developer. However, I need to run this trigger in Java code(spring controller). ıs it possible? Thanks

Comment: Do you have hibernate integration in your application or are you using any ORM framework to work with your DB?

Comment: I am using Hibernate integration.

Answer (score 0):

Since your trigger is defined at the DB level, insertion from anywhere (Spring Controller, SQL Developer) should also invoke the trigger. I don't think you need a separate logic for invoking DB triggers, they are invoked based on the trigger event you have specified.